# connect remote server with localhost

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, foreign-data-wrapper

I have a postgresql database that is in the cloud, and I want to connect this remote database to my localhost using foreign table, so I did:

```sql
CREATE SERVER testeServer
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host 'my ip v4', port '5432',dbname 'my db');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR my user
SERVER testeServer
OPTIONS (user 'userlocal', password 'passuserlocal');

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
LIMIT TO (jsontest, json, jsonlog) 
FROM SERVER testeServer 
INTO public;
```

I got my ip from my cmd by running the ipconfig command
getting the parameter: IPv4 address

The creation of the server and user mapping happen normally, but the import of the schema to the server does not happen the way it should and gives me this error:

> ERROR: could not connect to server "testeserver"
> Detalhe: connection to server at "my ip", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I read some articles that asked me to change some postgresql files, like pg_hba.conf
mine is like this:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                         scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all                 0.0.0.0/0            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all                 ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                         scram-sha-256
host    replication     all                  127.0.0.1/32           scram-sha-256
host    replication     all                  ::1/128                scram-sha-256
```

mine looked like this: `listen_addresses = "*"`

I also defined entry rules in my firewall, but it still didn't work, I disabled the firewall, and it didn't work either

I don't know if I was very clear in what I'm trying to do, what I did:

I connected to my cloud server using dbeaver, and on my localhost I have data that I want to pass to the server in the cloud, that's why I'm taking this approach..

even with all the changes I showed above, why do I get the error:

> ERROR: could not connect to server "testeserver"
> Detalhe: connection to server at "my ip", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I'm using Windows 11

Comment: There is a firewall between the two servers which is blocking the connection.  You said you disabled the firewall, but there can be any number of firewalls between two machines and it only takes one of them to ruin your day.